# What is the point in specifying types when extending tsconfig?

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I have an angular app that uses @types and some custom typings. For some reason when I serve the app it works, and when I run my tests using ng test it cant find the custom typings. I cant understand why that is anymore and I dont understand how you're supposed to manage extending the config or why you would want different typings available between serving and testing.

Here is my configs that were auto generated:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : true,
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I have tried many different variations and still dont understand why it works on serving but not testing. I understand that not specifying the types array means that all types should be grabbed? Yet the opposite seems to be true.

If anyone can shed some light I'd appreciate it.

Comment: First, simple question : do you run your command from the root folder, or are you in a subfolder ?

Comment: root folder for both commands

Comment: Okay, and did you try removing `**/*.d.ts` from the `include` of your test config ?

Comment: without it I get compilation errors, with it I get runtime errors

Comment: And did you try adding `"types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]` to your spec file ? (in `compilerOptions`)

Comment: keeping the *.d.ts line or removing it and adding "types": [ "jasmine", "node" ] produces errors about custom typings.

Comment: Then sorry, I'm out of suggestions ...

Comment: Thanks for trying :)

Comment: That's the least I could do, good luck with your issue ! By the way, if you can provide a [mcve], it would be awesome to have one !

Comment: Ok, so it turns out Im just dumb. for reasons the project Im working on started off using globals for quite a lot of things and one of those was the type that wasnt working. these globals got set in main.ts which only runs when you serve an angular app, not when you run specs. Hence no globabl function set, type doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was not caused by missing type, rather by missing global function for type.